# RCurl_1.95-3 can not deal with pages in Chinese characters

Tags: r, rcurl, chinese-locale

I updated RCurl package to 1.95-3. I have found that it can not deal with pages in Chinese characters.

Here is an example:

library(RCurl)

url="http://vip.stock.finance.sina.com.cn/corp/go.php/vMS_FuQuanMarketHistory/stockid/601117.phtml"

txt <- getURL(url, .encoding = "GB2312")

I got the following error information.
Error in nchar(str) : invalid multibyte string 1

`getURL` is not working in this example.

I re-installed RCurl 1.91 and found that the above code worked.  Anyone know how to solve this without resorting to downgrading RCurl?

Comment: I get a 404 error on that URL. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: I can use RCurl to scrape web pages in Chineses before I update RCurl to the latest version.

Comment: is the url not `http://finance.sina.com.cn/money/` ?

Comment: Yes, should be http://finance.sina.com.cn/money/

Comment: Works for me with RCurl 1.95-1.1 if anyone wants to narrow down the bug (assuming its a bug, I've not tried 1.95-3 yet...)

Comment: DONT just say "is not working". Give the error message or other reason its not working (maybe `txt` is returned as an empty string or something).

Comment: I edited the original url and added the error information.